# Handling inbound SOAP messages with an application server

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, handler, message

I know the concept of handling SOAP messages with Handlers (jax-ws) or Interceptors (CXF) to secure messages, doing logging and so on.
These handlers for inbound messages can be defined in a chains. So good so far.

Assume you host an external service on your application server and you want to secure this service or you want to add specific logging to it. 
How do you achieve this purpose without changing the code/configuration of this service?
Is there any common way to configure a handler for all (or a defined set of) services deployed on an application server?

I didn't specify the application server because I need a way to achieve these goals on a websphere as well as a JBoss or a Jetty/Tomcat.

Hope my questions were clear enough ;-)